# Java ElasticSearch API

Tags: java, rest, api, elasticsearch

We have an existing POC client-side javascript application which queries elasticsearch using pre-defined lumps of JSON (fairly complicated queries)

To move this project along a bit I'm going to rewrite this using java to perform the queries. What is the easiest way to do this? Should I use the JavaAPI for ElasticSearch or use the Java REST API.

It's clear that the REST API is lower-level and would be easier to adapt our current code but when we come to eventually improve our queries (read: re-write) it'll be easier to use the JavaAPI

Is there a middle ground? I don't see how to use the current version (5.0) of the API with JSON strings, I've read that the REST API supports this out of the box but once we use this we'll have to re-implement everything when we come to the refactoring process.

Thanks

Gordon